# LdapAuth in cakephp 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i try to program a LdapAuthentication and i need some help.

First i need to configure the "$components" in /app/Controller/
Component/AppController.php

```
<?php
  class AppController extends Controller {
  var $components = array('Auth' => array(
                            'Ldap',
                            'authError' => 'Not allowed here',                         
                           'authenticate' => array('Form' => array(
                                              'fields' => array(
                                                   'username'    => 'username',
                                                   'password' => 'password',
                                                    'domain' => 'domain'
                                     )
                                )
                            ),
                            'authorize' => true,
                          ), 'Session');
                  }
                      ?>
```

Then i create a LdapAuthorize.php like
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authorize-objects

```
              <?php
              App::uses('BaseAuthorize', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

            class LdapAuthorize extends BaseAuthorize {
            public function authorize($user, CakeRequest $request) {
            echo "test";
                }
                 }

              ?>
```

But when i try to login with

```
          if ($this->Auth->login()) {
           return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
          } else {
               $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'),
            'default', array(), 'auth');
              }
```

cakephp doesn't use my authorize function.

What i do wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working Ldap Auth class for 2.0.x

https://github.com/analogrithems/idbroker/tree/dev_cake2.0

with a blog post detailing it here:

http://www.analogrithems.com/rant/2012/01/03/cakephp-2-0-ldapauth/

** ALSO **

Your Auth configuration is wrong - the authorize key takes a string or array - a boolean true isn't going to do anything.

If you want it to check an isAuthorized action in the controller - set it like so:

```
<?php
    ...
    public $components = array( 'Auth' => array(
        ...
        'authorize' => array( 'Controller' ),
        ...
    ));
?>
```

You are passing a boolean parameter here, and have no isAuthorized function in your AppController. Also, you are using old php4 syntax to declare your member variables (use public, protected or private instead of "var")

Comment: Why did you change your mind about this being an acceptable answer? The Auth class works and my note about your config is 100% accurate.

Comment: Seconde link does not work. [Link](http://www.analogrithems.com/rant/cakephp-2-0-ldapauth/)