# CakePHP 2.x: Why is my /admin/user/login stuck in a redirect loop?

Tags: cakephp, admin, cakephp-2.x

I have created a little project with an admin section. I am using admin routes to redirect to admin actions in my controllers. The website has pages that are available to everyone with no login required. To access the /admin or /admin/users, etc... You must login.

I have spread my admin actions across my controllers like "admin_login", "admin_users", ...

So my question is, when someone goes to /admin/users or some other adminpage, I have to check in each controller action if the user is in the session and otherwise redirect to thelogin form.

Is there a way to do this in one place? I used a beforefilter in my AppController class.

When using something like this, I get an infinite loop:

## AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $helpers = array('Paginator','Acl.AclHtml');
    public $components = array('Acl', 'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authError' => 'You are not authorized to access that location.',
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array(
                    'actionPath' => 'controllers')
            ),
            'controllers' => array('users')
        ));


    public function beforeFilter() {
        if(isset($this->request->prefix) && ($this->request->prefix == 'admin')){
            $username = $this->Session->read('Admin.username');
            if (empty($username)) {
                $this->redirect (array(
                    'controller'=>'users',
                    'action'=>'login',
                    'admin'=>true
                ));
            } else {
                $this->redirect (array(
                    'controller'=>'admin',
                    'action'=>'dashboard',
                    'admin'=>true
                ));

            }
        } 

        // LDAP
        $server_ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        $ldapIp = ClassRegistry::init('LdapIp');
        $ldapIpCount = $ldapIp->find('count', array('conditions' => array('ldap_ip' => $server_ip)));
        if ($ldapIpCount >= 1) {
            $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Ldap');
        } else {
            $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form');
        }
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form');

        $this->Auth->allow();

        if (!$this->Auth->isAllow($this)) {
            $this->set(array(
                'message' => array(
                    'text' => __('un aunthaticated request'),
                    'type' => 'error',
                    'status' => "401"
                ),
                '_serialize' => array('message')
            ));
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }
    }
}
```

The front login with LDAP (Active directory).

## UsersController.php

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session', 'RequestHandler', 'Auth', 'Acl');

    public function admin_login() {
        $this->layout = 'admin_login';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $username = $this->request->data['User']['username'];
            $password = $this->request->data['User']['password'];
            $password = Security::hash($password, null, true);
            $logged_in = $this->User->find('count', array('conditions' => array('User.username' => $username, 'User.password' => $password, 'User.role' => 'Admin', 'User.active' => 1)));
            if ($logged_in >= 1) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Login successful!'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
                $users = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.username' => $username, 'User.password' => $password, 'User.role' => 'Admin', 'User.active' => 1)));
                $this->Session->write('Admin.id', $users['User']['id']);
                $this->Session->write('Admin.username', $users['User']['username']);
                $this->Session->write('Admin.group_id', $users['User']['group_id']);
                $this->Session->write('Admin.full_name', $users['UserProfile']['fname'] . " " . $users['UserProfile']['lname']);

                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'dashboard', 'admin' => true));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect!'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-error'));
            }
        }
    }

    public function admin_logout() {
        $this->Session->delete("Admin");
        //$this->Session->destroy();
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Logged out successful!'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you believe the answer below helped you, please mark it as accepted. I've noticed that -so far- you've never accepted an answer in Stack Overflow. This will help focus on your unanswered questions, and motivate other members to provide helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy are getting an infinite loop because `beforeFilter()` will be called when you attempt to access `/admin/users/login`.

The proper way of dealing with your needs is setting up the [Auth Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html).

Once you've set up component, in `UsersController::beforeFilter()` you have to allow access to those actions that don't require login by means of the `allow()` method. E.g.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow(array('signup'));
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

This is also applicable to any other controller with actions that need to be accessed by non logged in users.

The `loginAction` you define in the Auth component configuration will be automatically allowed access.

In the [blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) you will find a good example of the Auth component usage.

### Edit

As mentioned, `AppController::beforeFilter()` is always called, even when you try to access `/admin/users/login`. To prevent this from happening, try adding the following condition:

```
if (empty($username) && $this->action!='login') {
    $this->redirect (array(
        'controller'=>'users',
        'action'=>'login',
        'admin'=>true
    ));
}
```

You wouldn't need this if you allowed `AuthComponent` to take care of authentication for you.

Still, there's no guarantee that your code will work as expected. You are making your life difficult by not using `AuthComponent` to its fullest. I recommend that you research on the topic:

- [Creating Custom Authorize objects](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authorize-objects) in the Cookbook 2.x
- [LdapAuth in cakephp 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9903787/3144159) in Stack Overflow

Comment: In my AppController have below code in beforefilter function if(isset($this->request->prefix) && ($this->request->prefix == 'admin')){
                $username = $this->Session->read('Admin.username');
                if (empty($username)) {
                    $this->redirect (array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login','admin'=>true));
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->redirect (array('controller'=>'admin','action'=>'dashboard','admin'=>true));
                }
            }

Comment: But still it is in infinaite loop

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code in your comment.

Comment: Hi Inigo Flores any comments

Comment: Thanks for your comments. How can I implement Auth component for Admin. Can you have any document that will explain step by step how to achieve this. or any kind of basic code that will get rid of me......

Comment: 'admin' is nothing special in CakePHP, except a prefix that you grant or forbid access based on user data by defining the `AppController::isAuthorized()` method. Please post this as a new question, as S.O. is going to start complaining there are too many comments . If you believe this answer has helped you so far, please mark it as accepted.